# iOS webview content does not fit on landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, jquery-mobile

I am using a webview to display google maps + jqmobile. Webview is resized properly on landscape and portrait, however, not its content that fits perfectly on portrait but not on landscape. I found some information that reports it as bug but I am not able to solve it. Thank you.

from jquery mobile .html I tried following configs,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;" />
```

from xcode .m file,

```
webView1.scalesPageToFit = YES;

NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[urlBase stringByAppendingString:@".html"]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10]; 

[webView1 loadRequest:req];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webview does not reload its contents when you rotate, so what you're seeing in landscape is the content sized to the portrait viewport. This also means it does not respect media queries on rotate like normal Mobile Safari does. Best solution is to reload the webview on rotate.

Comment: thank you for your answer, your solution works but problem is that when reloading content, alertView asking for GPS permission appears again! any way to dismiss it?

Comment: If that alert is coming up every time, chances are the response isn't being captured. Does it also come up every time you reload the view controller? If so, it's a problem with the website.

Comment: yes, comes up every time that webview is reloaded. I do not know exactly how to keep gps permission during the session, modifying jqmobile html or objective-c code...